# SVN : How to prevent SVN commit if specific word is present if file

Tags: svn

I want to prevent SVN commit ..if in JAVA file below mention lines are present..

```
System.out.println();
printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pre commit hook to run a script just prior to commit completion.

Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181997/hook-script-to-block-commit-of-files-having-a-particular-string) for sample script scanning for particular string.